# Draw border around your paper in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, raphael

Okay...extremely new to Raphael.

Anyway, how do I draw a border around my drawing so I can see the size of my canvass?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

          var paper = Raphael('drawing', 100, 100);
          var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 30);
          var rectangle = paper.rect(60, 60, 100, 20, 5);
          var filler = { fill: 'red', cursor: 'pointer' };

          circle.attr(filler);
          circle.node.id = 'myCircle';

          rectangle.attr(filler);
     });
</script>

<div id="drawing" class="canvass">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that by default, your div is going to fill any available width, so it will not necessarily be the same dimensions as the canvas.

I don't think Raphael allows you to do it directly, but here is a way you can do it using jQuery:

```
$('div#drawing').find('> svg,div').css({'border': '1px solid #f00'});
```

Or you can just use CSS in a similar way:

```
div#drawing svg, div#drawing div {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified the size of canvas here: Raphael('drawing', 100, 100);

That line means: inside the drawing element add an 100x100 canvas.

If you want to add a border the simplest and most correct way to do that is to just border the div.

```
  <div id="drawing" style="border 2px solid #f00;" class="canvass"></div>
```

That should do it.

Comment: So you CANNOT put a border around the paper?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using jQuery in your code, you can easily use [Raphael.glow element.](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.glow)

I was trying to add border for my Raphael image element but css border or stroke didn't work out as entire space is filled out by default.
I came across this wonderful feature in [Raphael reference](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html).

- Glow acts as an element attached over your image/paper as border and you can easily use for  debug.

Template and example as below :

```
div.glow(width,fill,opcity,offsetX,offsetY,color)
paper.glow(10,true);
```